# Creating array of int from array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array of objects:

```
this.clients=[{firstName:"Tywin", lastName:"Lannister", age:46, id:2},
              {firstName:"Arya", lastName:"Starck", age:46, id:-1},
              {firstName:"John", lastName:"Snow", age:46, id:12},
              {firstName:"Robb", lastName:"Starck", age:46, id:24}];
```

And this variable:

```
var idArr;
```

I need to iterate threw all objects in array and get all id's and create array from them.Like that:

```
idArr = [2,-1,12,24]
```

How can I implement it using lodash?

Comment: Have you searched? What have you found?

Comment: The lodash examples aren't sufficient to figure this out? Doesn't seem like any research effort was done on this

Answer (score 5):

Use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method

```js
this.clients=[{firstName:"Tywin", lastName:"Lannister", age:46, id:2},
              {firstName:"Arya", lastName:"Starck", age:46, id:-1},
              {firstName:"John", lastName:"Snow", age:46, id:12},
              {firstName:"Robb", lastName:"Starck", age:46, id:24}];

var idArr = this.clients.map(function(v){ return v.id; })

console.log(idArr);
```

Comment: Any idea why I get syntex error on this "=>"

Comment: @Michael because arrow functions are ES6 and only supported in strict mode (`'use strict'`) in modern browsers. Check the duplicate question in my comment to your answer for a version with a regular callback function.

Comment: @Michael : it's ES6 arrow function, only works in latest browser.... so answer updated with normal function